# How to convert a XLSX file to PDF with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, xlsx

I have an .xlsx file I generate using xlsxwriter in a python script (version 2.7). I am trying to find a way to convert a worksheet in the file to a PDF format. I have not found a module that suits my needs yet.. simple, lightweight, and is able to be installed using pip.

Any suggestions, let's hear them! Thanks to all!

Comment: Perhaps take a look at https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/53

Comment: @A.Thom, were you able to get a solution to this problem???? I have the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a comdination of openpyxl and PDFwriter as shown in [this example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/579128-convert-microsot-excel-xlsx-to-pdf-with-python-and/) this example